# How to work PyTorch's zero_grad(), backward() and step()

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I have a basic linear regression class which created by nn.module, here is the class:

```
class LinearRegressionModel2(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    # Use nn.Linear() for creating the model parameters (also called linear transform, probing layer, fully connected layer, dense layer)
    self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(in_features = 1,
                                  out_features = 1)

  def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    return self.linear_layer(x)
```

And I tried to make basic prediction with test and train loop before the loop step I created loss function and optimizer, here is the reletad codes:

```
torch.manual_seed(42)
model_1 = LinearRegressionModel2()

# Setup Loss Function
loss_fn = nn.L1Loss() # Same ass MAE

# Setup our optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params = model_1.parameters(),
                            lr = 0.01, )

epochs = 200

for epoch in range(epochs):
  model_1.train()

  # 1. Forward pass
  y_pred = model_1(X_train)

  # 2. Calculate the loss
  train_loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)
  
  # 3. Optimizer zero grad
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  # 4. Perform backpropagation
  train_loss.backward()

  # 5. Optimizer step
  optimizer.step()

  ### Testing
  model_1.eval()
  with torch.inference_mode():
    test_pred = model_1(X_test)
    test_loss = loss_fn(test_pred, y_test)

  # Print out whats happening

  if epoch % 10 == 0:
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch} | Train Loss: {train_loss} | Test Loss: {test_loss}")
```

But I cant understand the 4. and 5. steps, when I searching in web, I found `optimizer.zero_grad()` uses for reset the gradient steps for every batch. 3. step is okey but in the 4. step how to backward() work with just with a numeric number, and after the 4. step how to optimizer known the loss train_loss.backward() and how this two steps work together because there are not have any connection in code.

In summary, how this 3. 4. and 5. steps work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 4. step how to backward() work with just with a numeric number

Your loss function is a convex function that in a way measures an error between ground truth values and predictions. Given this value, inputs and all computations that resulted in it, you could compute derivatives for each operation, for example, a network's dense layer.

> and how this two steps work together because there are not have any
> connection in code.

When you initialise an optimizer, you have to provide all the parameters subject to optimisation:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params = **model_1.parameters()**,
                            lr = 0.01, )
```

Internally, pytorch does all required magic and bookkeeping on all the computations happening.

So, overall:

1. Given some inputs, current set of parameters, compute predictions with forward pass
2. Compute a difference between predictions and ground truth values with loss function
3. Compute derivatives for each parameter of your model with the error you've measured at step 2 - backward pass. This step pytorch performs internally, you should not do anything yourself
4. Update model's parameters with some rule - optimizer.step()
5. Drop all results before the next step - zero_grad() so you could repeat this process

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand `optimizer.zero_grad()` and `optimizer.step()`. But still I can not understand, how to `optimizer.step()` known the our loss value which is calculated in step 2 and our loss.backward() result in step 4. Because `optimizer.step()` have to know these values for updating parameters. Also still I have doubts about `loss.backward()`  work

Comment: Each model's parameter internally has attached gradient value. When you do zero_grad, step or backwards, these gradient values are got updated - a loss function and an optimizer both have access to them. The loss function knows about parameters from predictions, the optimizer knows about them since you directly give it all parameters.

Comment: As for backward pass, check this tutorial, it's pretty useful https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#differentiation-in-autograd